# How to center align buttons in a modal content?

Tags: html, css

I have 6 buttons in my modal, I'm trying to make them center + vertical align in the page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="feedModal">
    <div class="model-content row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 text-center">

            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >1 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >2 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >3 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >4 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >5 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >6 oz </a>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.btn-amount {
    background: #ffffff4f !important; 
    border: white 1px solid !important; 
    height: 50px; 
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
}

.btn-amount:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px white;
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center an element horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to achive this, but as per my opinion use of `flex` is the one you should go with,

1. Give `display:flex;` to the parent in which your child element is to them you want to do the center.
2. `justify-content` is the property which will adjust items on **X** axes and in case of `flex-direction: column;` it will adjust the items on **Y** axes.
3. `align-items` is the property which will adjust items on **Y** axes and in case of `flex-direction: column;` it will adjust the items on **X** axes.
4. so if you want your child elements to make them center on both the axes, then use `align-items:center` and `justify-content: center;` on the parent, it will make your child elements center on both the axes as shown in your image,

```css
.btn-amount {
    background: #fff !important; 
    border: #fff 1px solid !important; 
    height: 50px; 
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
}

.btn-amount:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px white;
}
.model-content {height: 300vh;//this is just for demo purpose}
.model-content > div {
width: 60%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
body {background-color: #000;}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="feedModal">
    <div class="model-content row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 text-center">

            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >1 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >2 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >3 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >4 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >5 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >6 oz </a>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used bootstrap grid because I’m only familiar with that right now.

Comment: if you used bootstrap, and I hope that you have used version 4 or above, then use these classes on your parent div, 1. d-flex ,2nd: flex-column, 3rd: justify-content-center and 4th :  align-items-center

it will do the exact same thing which I did with code.

Comment: yes its free and better in every term, but if dont want to change the bootstrap version , then use the css I have given in above example, that will work with BS3 as well because thats just pure css

Comment: Why need `height: 300vh;` ?

Comment: I have mentioned there read comment after height property, that its just for demo purpose my friend, no need of that in your code, here we dont have that much height and to show your buttons in center, you can ignore it completely

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="feedModal">
    <div class="model-content row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 text-center">

            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >1 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >2 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >3 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >4 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >5 oz </a>
            <a data-type="feed" onclick="playSound('feed')" class="btn btn-amount col-xs-12 col-sm-2" >6 oz </a>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sometimes a problem need a simple solution,try:

```css
  .btn-amount {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  .btn-amount:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .btn-amount:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
```

this solution will give all of your div margin so they won't stick each other.
& you can change the margin-top and margin-bottom style.

Comment: I like this simple solution.

Comment: this solution will not work on this, because there are 6 buttons, and your are applying css on a common class, it will make the pile of these 6 buttons over one another,